# JQuery - Adding class onto element, and then interacting with that class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click `( ".toggle-button a" )`, it adds `.close` class to itself. And fades in `.info-overlay`

This works fine, but when you click it again, I want `info-overlay` to fade out again, and the `close` class to be removed. But this doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/xpS9P/1/

html

```
<div class="toggle-button">
<a>click</a>
</div>
<div class="info-overlay">
content
</div>
```

css

```
.info-overlay{
display:block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:green;
display:none;
};
```

js

```
    $( ".toggle-button a" ).click(function() {
    $( ".info-overlay" ).fadeIn("500");
    $(this).addClass('close');
});
$( ".toggle-button a.close" ).click(function(){
    $( ".info-overlay").fadeOut("500");
    $(this).removeClass('close');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation:

Change

```
$( ".toggle-button a.close" ).click(function(){
    $( ".info-overlay").fadeOut("500");
    $(this).removeClass('close');
});
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click',".toggle-button a.close",function(){
    $( ".info-overlay").fadeOut("500");
    $(this).removeClass('close');
});
```

Because a `.click()` is attach and forget handler, but `.on()` is dynamic.

Comment: To make it clearer,  .click() hooks on to a.close and listens for a click. $(document).on() listens for a click and checks if what you clicked on was a.close

Answer (score 0):

**[see updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpS9P/3/)**

```
    $( ".toggle-button a" ).click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('close')){
        $( ".info-overlay").fadeOut("500");
         $(this).removeClass('close');
        }else{
        $( ".info-overlay" ).fadeIn("500");
        $(this).addClass('close');
    }
    });
```

reference **[hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use delegation or just set your logic as following:

### DEMO

```
$(".toggle-button a").click(function () {
    $(".info-overlay").fadeToggle(500).toggleClass('close');
});
```